# Python keyboard controls

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

Here is my code I have trouble with, it's a basic side scroller game but I am having troubles with my keyboard control definitions, they don't seem to work, and I can't find the problem.

```
if keys[K_LEFT]:
    newmove= LEFT
    moveLeft(guy,10)
    climb(guy)      
if keys[K_RIGHT]:
    newmove=RIGHT
    moveRight(guy,10)
    climb(guy)
if keys[K_SPACE] and guy[ONGROUND]:
    guy[VY] = -14

else:
    frame=0

if move==newmove:
    frame=frame+0.1
    if frame>=len(pics[move]):
        frame=1
elif newmove!=-1:
    move=newmove
    frame=1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a minimal example that we can actually run. That's not enough of your code to find the mistake. A more detailed question would also be nice.

Comment: Where are you moving the player?What errors you encountered while trying to solve your problem? Please let us know this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this? or something like this?

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    xChange = -5
                    print("Left")
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    xChange = 5
                    print("Right")
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    xChange = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    xChange = 0
```